# Videos Playing Way too Fast

Tags: video

Recently installed 16.10.  All is working quite well, with the exception of videos playing 10x+.

Whether it be in Firefox or Chrome, Facebook or Youtube, all videos are playing extremely fast.

I have currently on kernel 4.9, but reverted back to 4.8 and the problem still exists.

I have no idea where to start on this one and searching doesn't bring up anything current.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently had the same problem for no readily apparent reason. I found a YouTube video which solved it - yes, I had to use pause a lot because it was playing too fast!

I had been using my laptop with an external monitor via HDMI and so switched the sound output to HDMI. When I got the problem I was not using the external monitor. The fix was to change my Sound Settings back to 'Speakers - Built-in Audio'. The problem was fixed immediately.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.